# Unable to load an xlxs spreadsheet into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb, docx4j

I want to implement a java desktop-application using eclipse that takes the information from the user and saves it into excel spreadsheet (using docx4j), but I faced a problem at the very beginning.

I'm trying to load the spreadsheet using this code:

```
private static void load(String filepath) {
    SpreadsheetMLPackage exc;
    try {
        exc = SpreadsheetMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(filepath));
    } catch (Docx4JException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
[main] ERROR org.docx4j.jaxb.Context - Cannot initialize context
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.plutext.jaxb.xmldsig" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.plutext.jaxb.xmldsig" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.docx4j.jaxb.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:158)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:679)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3.get(Load3.java:132)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:454)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:371)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:262)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:242)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.SpreadsheetMLPackage.load(SpreadsheetMLPackage.java:97)
```

Note:
1- Creating new spreadsheet works fine. 2- The external jars added to my project are: docx4j-3.2.1, jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12, slf4j-api-1.7.12, slf4j-simple-1.7.12.
3- I searched for a solution on google and I found that I must add org.apache.xalan and org.apache.xml.serializer jars to my project but still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include all docx4j's dependencies.

The cause of this specific error is missing http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-3_2_0/dependencies/jaxb-xmldsig-core-1.0.0.jar